# What is the django equivalent of Jinja2 batch filter?

Tags: django, templates, jinja2, django-1.10

I am trying to use django 1.10 templating system to display a list as a sequence of row, each containing at most 3 columns. In Jinja2 I would write:

```
{% for items in all_items|batch(3) %}
    <div class="row">
    {% for item in items %}
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <h1> {{item.name}} </h1>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Using the batch filter in Jinja2 produces the desired output. I could not find an equivalent filter in django templates. What is the django way to achieve this ?

Comment: Have you tried to use slice?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#slice

Comment: @MehdiPourfar it appears to me that slice will give me a subset of the all_items list, i'm looking to build a list of lists of size at most 3. I'm looking for the built-in way [to do this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7374167/856645)

Comment: There isn't a built in equivalent of bunch. You can either write a custom template filter, or use `forloop.counter` variable and `divisibleby` in the template.

Comment: @Alasdair I see. The answers to the similar question are fine for my use case. Thanks